# QueryDsl cross join returns zero elements

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

Hello I got stuck a little bit with querydsl (+hibernate 4.2.3 and postgresql). Generally it works pretty well, but then i have one predicate built like this:

```
QUser user = QUser.user;
....
predicate = and(predicate,
                user.userType.in(userTypes)
                .or(user.customer.userType.in(userTypes)));
```

Now the problem is that user does not always have customer. Querydsl generates sql with cross join to customer table, and when user does not have customer this query returns zero entries even though those entries should be returned. This customer has left join (modified spring data a bit to allow join fetch fields) but for it still creates additional cross join. Any ideas how to write such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the user.customer traversal to create the additional join.

The following query should work

```
query.from(user)
     .leftJoin(user.customer, customer)
     .where(user.userType.in(userTypes).or(customer.userType.in(userTypes)));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for an idea. I know that left join would work, but the problem is that before I use dynamic query building with PathBuilder and then pass that constructed predicate to this method to further filter by userTypes and then that predicate is passed to spring data repository listAll() method. I modified it a bit to have my fields fetched. But its done like this: fetchQuery.leftJoin(builder.get(fetchField)).fetch(); I used it to have some fields fetched easily by just providing list of strings with fetchField names. This helped me to avoid lazy initialization exception.

Comment: So the problem is I don't know how to use that join fetched customer as predicate is built separately from query execution.

Comment: You need to give it an alias to be able to refer to it: leftJoin(property, alias).fetch()